# Gradle and Android: obtain package ID from Android Library Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android project created with Android Studio that uses the Gradle build system.

I have several modules (subprojects) in this Android project, and some of them are Android Library projects (AAR).

What I need to do is obtain the Package ID (basically the value that uniquely identifies an Android app or library, the one thay is found in the AndroidManifest.xml file inside the "package" attribute) from these AAR projects from Gradle.

Now, if the project was an android **app** it would be trivial: the "android.defaultConfig.applicationId" property already contains the package ID.

But for Android **library** projects this value is not available.
Now, I know I can technically just use the (very flexible) groovy XML parser to read the value directly from the AndroidManifest.xml file, but I was wondering if there was a more direct and efficient way to do it, like there is for Android apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I didn't find a more direct solution to this, here's how I did it with pure Gradle code in the end:

```
File pluginManifestFile = file(project.absolutePath + "/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    if(pluginManifestFile.exists()){
        String manifestContents = pluginManifestFile.text
        def pluginManifestXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(manifestContents)
        String packageName = pluginManifestXml.@package.toString()
        println 'Package name of the library is: ' + packageName
    }
```